# SwiftUI: Weird dismiss animation on iPad popover

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

When I create a popover on my iPad and start using split screen mode, the popover automatically transforms into a sheet. But unfortunately it is only dismissable with a weird kind of animation.

[image]

I don't think that apple wants developers to just deal with this weird behaviour since using split screen is a nice feature to use. Also there are popovers in apps such as the appstore where you can open popovers which transform to nice dismissable sheets in smaller screenclasses.

I already tried to handle the problem with conditional modifiers which apply when the screensize is either .regular oder .compact and assign either a sheet or a popover with

```swift
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, content: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            content(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

but unfortunately I can't predictably controll the popoverIsShown state anymore when modifiers are closed and opened by the sizeClass.

Is there any other suitable workaround for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a solution that works really fine for myself. It may help people facing the same problem someday.

1. Define sizeclasses and the presentation state in your main view

```swift
@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
@State var ispresent = true
```

2. Write own modifier which assigns either a sheet or a popover to your main view depending on the given sizeclass

```swift
struct PopoverSheet: ViewModifier {
    var size: UserInterfaceSizeClass?
    @Binding var isPresented:Bool
    var sheetContent: AnyView
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        VStack {
            if size == .compact {
                content
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresented){
                        self.sheetContent
                    }
            } else {
                content
                    .popover(isPresented: self.$isPresented){
                        self.sheetContent
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Extend the View Class so that you can easily add the modifier to your main view

```swift
extension View {
    func popoverSheet(sizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?, isPresented: Binding<Bool>, sheetContent: AnyView) -> some View {
        modifier(PopoverSheet(size: sizeClass, isPresented: isPresented, sheetContent: sheetContent))
    }
}
```

4. Simply add the modifier to your main view

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.ispresent = false
                // NEED TO RETOGGLE THE SHEET AFTER CHANGING SIZECLASSES
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1){
                    self.ispresent.toggle()
                }
            }){
                Text("Toggle Popover")
            }
            .popoverSheet(sizeClass: horizontalSizeClass,
                          isPresented: self.$ispresent,
                          sheetContent: AnyView(ThePopoverView(content: "Popover Content with any arguments")))
        }
    }
```